# Setting a server control property from the content page

Tags: asp.net

I need to validate a textbox to ensure the submit date is older than Today. I wanted to use a CompareValidator to do that, but unfortunately the following code doesn't work:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvtbDateExpiration" ControlToValidate="tbDateExpiration"
    Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date" ValueToCompare="<%= DateTime.Today %>"   
    ErrorMessage="Card has expired" runat="server" />
```

The compiler tells me that `ValueToCompare="<%= DateTime.Today %>"` is wrong: "This is not scriptlet. Will be output as plain text."

Is there a simple way to achieve this (without setting it using the Code Behind)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's generally set as follows:

```
ValueToCompare='<%# DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'
```

... and you have to call **DataBind()** on the control (directly or indirectly).